# How I do to "migrate" the structure from aspnetdb.mdf to a mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, web-deployment

I'm creating a new Asp.Net MVC 3 application. Visual Studio does a lot of the job of create the database and initial layout. Very nice! I will upload that initial files to my server, but I want that it runs using the MySql database on the server.

There's some quick/easy way to do it? I'm not worried about the data, just the structure of the tables, and the connection/configuration changes.

Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I setup ASP.NET MVC 2 with MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512852/how-do-i-setup-asp-net-mvc-2-with-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You can export any MS-SQL database as a Script (Sql Server manager).
Fix it up to make it compatible.

But you will also need a [Membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx), look around if there exist any for MySql, otherwise you'll have to create one ([movie](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider)).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of tools listed in "[Migrating from Microsoft SQL Server and Access to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/migrating-from-microsoft.html)".

Or (assuming that you're using column types that exist on both platforms) you can write a script to convert a schema dump from SqlServer into MySQL (or do the conversion by hand in a text editor). Even better yet, you can write a program program to read the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` table from SqlServer and produce the necessary `CREATE TABLE...` statements in mysql. Lots of options.