# Switching new mvc app template to use mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

Im trying switch the Visual Studio asp.net mvc web app template to use MySql for user auth. So far iv installed mysql and .net connectors, created a custom membership provider (although it just throws notsupported atm) and edited the web.config to use them. But no matter what I try i just keep getting the following...

> "Failed to generate a user instance of
>   SQL Server due to failure in
>   retrieving the user's local
>   application data path. Please make
>   sure the user has a local user profile
>   on the computer. The connection will
>   be closed."

I've even searched the entire solution for any reference to sql to make sure its not set somewhere I was'nt expecting it too.

accompanying config is as follows...

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySqlMembershipConnection"
    connectionString="Data Source=server_name;
                      user id=username;
                      password=password;
                      database=database_name;"
    providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

<membership>
      <providers>
        <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" type="testmvcappp.MySqlMembershipProvider" />
      </providers>
<membership>
```

Thanks, Tom.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I setup ASP.NET MVC 2 with MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512852/how-do-i-setup-asp-net-mvc-2-with-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOt sure, but a couple thoughts.

1) It's a generally good practice to call <clear/> in your providers list first to make sure that nothing was set in a "higher" web.config.

2) Is your custom membership provider inheriting from ProviderBase or from the SqlMembershipProvider?  If the latter, it may be calling the inherited setup methods

Comment: hey, my custom provider is inheriting from 'MembershipProvider'?

Comment: That should be fine.  Do you have any of the other default stuff in the web.config still, perhaps?  I mean, are you certain that none of the other services aren't registered w/ the default Sql implementations?

Comment: Yeee sorted it out :), the problem was i needed to explicitly remove the default provider <remove name="AspNetSqlProvider" />, seems a bit crazy to me but hey.

Comment: Right, my #1 was supposed to tell you to use the clear tag to dump all the default providers, but I only just noticed that I had used the regular &lt; instead of the html entity, so it got swallowed by Stack's input validation mechanism.

Comment: aaaaaah right ok :D cool, guess you did answer my question after all!