# Creating Database Model on ASP.NET MVC with MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I'm using ASP.NET C# with database MYSQL, I follow this step on creating a database model with Entity Data Model Wizard http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/movie-database/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-cs. When I run this, it showed error --> Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO).

I already have connection with the same connection string uses on webconfig MySQLMembershp I copied from this [How do I setup ASP.NET MVC 2 with MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512852/how-do-i-setup-asp-net-mvc-2-with-mysql) which is working.

if they have the same connection string uses this should work, but why is not working when I create a database model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all EF model connectionstring and Asp.NET membership connectionstring is different. Secondly you may have to see how EF model works using MySQL database here

[Getting MySQL work with Entity Framework 4.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/12/09/getting-mysql-work-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the reply wonde, yes i know they are different, but there mysqlconnection string are the same. upon looking on the web.i foond this report from mysql <http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61230>. btw ur link is helpful thanks you for this.

Comment: The link from Mark Yu had the solution for me in a comment:[29 Sep 2011 1:43] Carno Mercado
Found the culprit, make sure the connection string should have the "Persist Security Info=True" option.

I can now refresh my model from DB, hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have no password. Have your tried using the **password** "root"?